# Varying separator colours in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an account page in my app where I would like to have account information displayed above the first section in a tableview, similar to the Apple ID page in the settings.

[image: AppleIDPage]

My question is based around how to structure the view such that there is no separator shown above the profile picture. Or to make it that the information appears to be within the tableview but not within a section.

From reading around it seems either not possible or very difficult to have some separators showing and others not.

In the case of the apple ID page, is that picture, name and email in its own section or a cell that is part of the section beneath it?

The following picture is the closest I have got although that top separator proves difficult to hide.

[image: MyAttempt]

Apologies for the broad nature of the question, however i think the aim is clear and once a solution is reached I will make the question more specific for future viewers.

Thanks.

Comment: I am appending `UIView` to a custom cell, place it like separator, hide default separator, so it is easy to hide/show/colour/whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dev and PGDev, I was able to come up with a nice solution that worked well for `static cells`. I made an `extension` for `UITableViewCell` that looks like this.

```
let separatorColour = UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 200/255, blue: 200/255, alpha: 0.5)

extension UITableViewCell {
    func separator(topInset: CGFloat, btmInset: CGFloat, showTop: Bool, showBtm: Bool) {
        
        if showTop {
            let topSeparator: UIView = UIView()
            topSeparator.frame = CGRect(x: topInset, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: 0.5)
            topSeparator.backgroundColor = separatorColour
            addSubview(topSeparator)
        }
        
        if showBtm {
            let btmSeparator: UIView = UIView()
            btmSeparator.frame = CGRect(x: btmInset, y: frame.height - 0.5, width: frame.width, height: 0.5)
            btmSeparator.backgroundColor = separatorColour
            addSubview(btmSeparator)
        }
    }
    
    func btnSeparator() {
        
            let topSeparator: UIView = UIView()
            topSeparator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: 0.5)
            topSeparator.backgroundColor = separatorColour
            addSubview(topSeparator)
        
            let btmSeparator: UIView = UIView()
            btmSeparator.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: frame.height - 0.5, width: frame.width - 32, height: 0.5)
            btmSeparator.backgroundColor = separatorColour
            addSubview(btmSeparator)
    }
}
```

In the first function `separator()` you can simply choose the inset for top and bottom `separator` and whether they are visible or not.

[image: screenshot1] [image: screenshot2]

**TopCell**
So in the case of the `cell` with the `name label` shown in the picture above, both top and bottom `separators` are visible. However because it is supposed to appear as the first `cell` in the section, it has no top inset and an appropriate bottom inset.

**MiddleCell**
In the case of the `cell` with the `email label` it only has the lower `separator` (with inset) visible as the `cell` above has a bottom `separator`.

**BottomCell**
For the `cell` with the `password label`, it only has the lower `separator` (without offset) visible as the `cell` above has a bottom `separator`.

**SpecialCase**
The `btnSeparator()` function was just for the case of the help and support button, where I wanted inset on both sides.

Now to implement this `extension`, I used a `switch statement` inside the `cellForRowAt` function to give each `cell` the appropriate `extension` and this is what that looks like:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
        let inset: CGFloat = 16        
        
        switch indexPath {
            
        // First Section
        case [0,1]:
            cell.separator(topInset: 0, btmInset: inset, showTop: true, showBtm: true)
        case [0,2]:
            cell.separator(topInset: inset, btmInset: inset, showTop: false, showBtm: true)
        case [0,3]:
            cell.separator(topInset: inset, btmInset: 0, showTop: false, showBtm: true)
            
        // Second Section
        case [1,0]:
            cell.separator(topInset: 0, btmInset: inset, showTop: true, showBtm: true)
        case [1,1]:
            cell.separator(topInset: inset, btmInset: inset, showTop: false, showBtm: true)
        case [1,2]:
            cell.separator(topInset: inset, btmInset: 0, showTop: false, showBtm: true)
            
        // Third Section
        case [2,0]:
            cell.btnSeparator()
        case [2,1]:
            cell.separator(topInset: inset, btmInset: 0, showTop: false, showBtm: true)
        case [2,3]:
            cell.separator(topInset: 0, btmInset: 0, showTop: true, showBtm: true)
            
        default:
            print("default")
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Be sure to set `separator` to none in the `Storyboard` or use:

`tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellStyle.None`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

//This will hide seperator for all rows

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellStyle.None
```

//For custom seperator

```
if indexPath.row != 0{
        var aView: UIView = UIView()
        aView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:44,width:300,height:1)
        aView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        cell .addSubview(aView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `custom view` in your `UITableViewCell` for that.

**1.** Set `UITableView` `Separator` to `none` in `storyboard`.

**2.** Create a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UIView` in it.

```
class TableCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var separatorView: UIView!
}
```

**3.** Set the `backgroundColor` of `separatorView` in `cellForRowAt` according to your requirement.

**Example:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableCell
    switch indexPath.row
    {
    case 0:
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    case 1:
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
    case 2:
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
    case 3:
        cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
    default:
        cell.backgroundColor = .orange
    }
    return cell
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]